# データフレームで特定の文字を含む要素を削除する

Tags: python, pandas

Pythonで、データフレーム中のある特定の文字を含む要素だけを消すことはできるのでしょうか。
以下では適当なデータフレームdfを作り、df3を「A」という文字が入る要素だけ取り除いたものにしようとしましたがErrorがでてしまいました。df4は「A」だけでなく「a」や「tu」も対象にしています。また、数字が入る要素は全て消したかったのですが方法がわからず、これに関しても教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['ABC','A','DE','900-D','B-255','DEF','300AF'],
 'Y': ['ux','tu5',29,'tuy3','ux3',0,'tux'],
 'Z': ['ab', '2ac', 'af', 'ad', 'bc3', 'df', 3]})
df

df2 = df.copy()

df3 = df2.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if 'A' in x else True)
df3

df4 = df2.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if 'A' or 'a' or 'tu' in x else True)
df4
```

Comment: df に `0` や `3` という数値が含まれていますので、`'A' in x` などでエラーになってしまいます。ですので、`df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if type(x) is str and 'A' in x else x)` などとすると良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ご指摘の通り変えましたらすぐにうまくいきました(^^) 'A'のあとに他の文字も付け足していっきに消すことができ、作業がスムーズになりました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こうゆうことですか？

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['ABC','A','DE','900-D','B-255','DEF','300AF'],
 'Y': ['ux','tu5',29,'tuy3','ux3',0,'tux'],
 'Z': ['ab', '2ac', 'af', 'ad', 'bc3', 'df', 3]})

# 'A'を取り除く
ret = df.apply(lambda d: d.str.contains('A', na=False))
print(df.mask(ret))
#        X     Y    Z
# 0    NaN    ux   ab
# 1    NaN   tu5  2ac
# 2     DE    29   af
# 3  900-D  tuy3   ad
# 4  B-255   ux3  bc3
# 5    DEF     0   df
# 6    NaN   tux    3


# 'A'と'a'を取り除く
ret = df.apply(lambda d: d.str.contains('A', case=False, na=False))
print(df.mask(ret))
#        X     Y    Z
# 0    NaN    ux  NaN
# 1    NaN   tu5  NaN
# 2     DE    29  NaN
# 3  900-D  tuy3  NaN
# 4  B-255   ux3  bc3
# 5    DEF     0   df
# 6    NaN   tux    3

# 'A'と'a'と'tu'を取り除く
ret = df.apply(lambda d: d.str.contains('A|a|tu', na=False))
print(df.mask(ret))
#        X    Y    Z
# 0    NaN   ux  NaN
# 1    NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2     DE   29  NaN
# 3  900-D  NaN  NaN
# 4  B-255  ux3  bc3
# 5    DEF    0   df
# 6    NaN  NaN    3

# 数字を含む文字列も削除
ret = df.apply(lambda d: d.str.contains('A|a|tu|\d', na=False, regex=True))
print(df.mask(ret))
#      X    Y    Z
# 0  NaN   ux  NaN
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2   DE   29  NaN
# 3  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 4  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 5  DEF    0   df
# 6  NaN  NaN    3

# データが文字列以外(数値データ)の場合も削除
ret = df.apply(lambda d: d.str.contains('A|a|tu|\d', na=True, regex=True))
print(df.mask(ret))
#      X    Y    Z
# 0  NaN   ux  NaN
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2   DE  NaN  NaN
# 3  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 4  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 5  DEF  NaN   df
# 6  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: そうです！完璧です！ありがとうございます。ちなみに、一番最後のデータフレームから数字の入ったものをNaNにするのはどうしたらよいですか？

Comment: 回答に数字の入ったものを削除する方法を追記しました

Comment: ありがとうございます。数字を含む文字列も数値データもきれいに消せました(^ ^)